# php create a multidimensioanal array

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating an array like this:

```
$result[$buyid.'_'.$freeid] = array(
    'itemquantity' => $v,
    'buyproduct' => $_POST['buyproduct'][$k],
    'buyproductid' => $buyid, 
    'freequantity' => $_POST['freequantity'][$k],
    'freeproduct' => $_POST['freeproduct'][$k],
    'freeproductid' => $freeid, 
);
```

Which outputs my array like this:

```
Array(
[53_53] => Array
    (
        [itemquantity] => 5
        [buyproduct] => 
        [buyproductid] => 53
        [freequantity] => 1
        [freeproduct] => 
        [freeproductid] => 53
    )

[53_38] => Array
    (
        [itemquantity] => 2
        [buyproduct] => 
        [buyproductid] => 53
        [freequantity] => 1
        [freeproduct] => 
        [freeproductid] => 38
    )

[31_31] => Array
    (
        [itemquantity] => 5
        [buyproduct] => 
        [buyproductid] => 31
        [freequantity] => 1
        [freeproduct] => 
        [freeproductid] => 31
    )
```

)

I would like to store my data slightly differently. I want to store it based on "buyproductid". So if there is more than one "buyproductid" it was create a child array. Something like this:

```
Array(
[53] => Array(
     [53] => Array(
        [itemquantity] => 5
        [buyproduct] => 
        [buyproductid] => 53
        [freequantity] => 1
        [freeproduct] => 
        [freeproductid] => 53
    ),
    [38] => Array(
        [itemquantity] => 5
        [buyproduct] => 
        [buyproductid] => 53
        [freequantity] => 1
        [freeproduct] => 
        [freeproductid] => 53
    )
```

),

```
[31] => Array(
    [31] => Array(
        [itemquantity] => 5
        [buyproduct] => 
        [buyproductid] => 31
        [freequantity] => 1
        [freeproduct] => 
        [freeproductid] => 31
    )

 )
```

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: `$result[$buyid][$freeid] = ...`?

Comment: Can you show us code which generates `$result` array

Answer (score 2):

You just need to alter the assignment syntax a little:

```
$result[$buyid][$freeid] = array(
    'itemquantity' => $v,
    'buyproduct' => $_POST['buyproduct'][$k],
    'buyproductid' => $buyid, 
    'freequantity' => $_POST['freequantity'][$k],
    'freeproduct' => $_POST['freeproduct'][$k],
    'freeproductid' => $freeid, 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to:

```
$result[$buyid][$freeid] = array(
    'itemquantity' => $v,
    'buyproduct' => $_POST['buyproduct'][$k],
    'buyproductid' => $buyid, 
    'freequantity' => $_POST['freequantity'][$k],
    'freeproduct' => $_POST['freeproduct'][$k],
    'freeproductid' => $freeid, 
);
```